# JDBC statements performance (setObject vs setInt , setString)

Tags: java, jdbc, bind-variables, java-binding

I have a program in which I bind the variables in a loop all using:

```
// Loop Start on i=1
preparedStatement.setObject(i , Val);
i++;
//Loop End
```

Some values are INT some are String etc.

I just want to know is is bad performance wise ? In other words ....

is  `setObject(1, "ABC")`   slower than `setString(1 , "ABC")`? Especially if there are a millions of bindings in a Loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927363/java-resultset-setobject-vs-setstring-setdate-etc?rq=1

Comment: Have you tested the performance of these two approaches?

Comment: cant test easily because I will have to change to code a lot

Comment: A little difference in time may occur basically in millisecs I am not sure of the exact reason but may be because in the case of preparedStatement.setString() or preparedStatement.setInt the JVM already knows of the type to deal with but in the later case it first clarifies the type and then acts accordingly. This may cause a little wastage of time i'm not quite sure here

Comment: There probably is a minor performance impact for using `setObject`, and it might vary per JDBC driver. Only way to find out for sure is to benchmark it thoroughly

Comment: @M.Sharma Technically the JVM doesn't 'clarify the type', this is explicitly programmed (eg using `instanceof`) in the specific JDBC driver implementation used.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Not quite sure what happens there actually as I said it was just an assumption someone can correct me if I am wrong